# Drag Race Countdown

Tags: code-golf, random

## Challenge:

In a hypothetical scenario, the countdown timer for a race has *random intervals* between the counts, to prevent premature starting, e.g.

```
3 (0.82 seconds pass), 2 (0.67 seconds pass), 1
```

---

## Input:

nothing

---

## Output:

Write a program (or function) that prints the 3 numbers with a random time interval from 0.50 seconds to 1 second between each count.

---

## Note:

- The program must output each number (3 , 2 , 1) with the random (*any* number between 0.50 and 1 to the hundredths; no hard-coding) time interval between each. The precision of the random interval must go out to the hundreds (e.g: 0.52). You are not required to output the interval, only the count.
- As @JoKing clarified, I mean uniformly random (you can use the pseudo-random generator of your language.
- As many people have clarified, I really mean any 2-decimal number between 0.5 and 1. (0.50, 0.51, etc, all the way to 0.98, 0.99, 1)

---

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the program with the lowest byte count wins.

Comment: Hi LordColus, and welcome to PPCG!  This seems like a good first challenge.  For future challenges, we recommend going through the [sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1) first to iron out all the details.

Comment: As I said in a previous comment that has been deleted, specifying "uniformly random" is fine if you are not too stringent with precision. As it stands now, the pause times must be uniform with precision of two decimals (or is it _at least_ two decimals?). Does that mean the distribution should be uniform on the set 0.5, 0.51, 0.52, ..., 1, or can it be any _floating point_ (possibly with more than two decimals) beween 0.5 and 1?

Comment: I mean that it can be any 2-digit decimal between 0.5 and 1

Comment: Does my most recent edit clear it up?

Comment: @LordColus I believe so. I voted to reopen already, so I cannot do it again.

Comment: @mbomb007 Same... why did this get closed again? It's basically count from 3 to 1 with two .50-1.00 second waits in between. It's really not complicated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 12 bytes

```
3LRε=₄D;ŸΩ.W
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/f2Cfo3FbbR00tLtZHd5xbqRf@/z8A)

---

```
3LR          # Push [3,2,1]
   ε         # For each...
    =        # Print it.
     ₄       # Push 1000.
      D      # Duplicate top (1000).
       ;     # Divided by 2 (500).
        Ÿ    # Range from b to a ([1000 .. 500]).
         Ω   # Random pick.
          .W # Wait X ms.
```

---

Try it with debug enabled: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/f2Cfo3FbbR00tLtZHd5xbqRf@//9/3RQA)

Answer (score 2):

## SmileBASIC, <s>64</s> 62 bytes

```
?3M?2M?1DEF M
M=MILLISEC
WHILE MILLISEC<M+500+RND(501)WEND
END
```

Unfortunately I can't use WAIT since that only supports intervals of 1/60 of a second (anything less isn't normally useful since input/output only update once per frame)

This requires adjustment depending on the speed of the system it's running on, so it might not be valid (46 bytes):

```
?3M?2M?1DEF M
FOR I=-66E4-RND(66E4)TO.NEXT
END
```

Invalid WAIT version (36 bytes):

```
?3WAIT 30+RND(30)?2WAIT 30+RND(30)?1
```

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>46</s> 44 bytes

for an actual countdown:

```r
for(i in 3:1){cat(i)
Sys.sleep(runif(1,.5))}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/Py2/SCNTITNPwdjKULM6ObFEI1OTK7iyWK84JzW1QKOoNC8zTcNQR89UU7P2/38A)

printing interval as I initially misunderstood the challenge (46 bytes)
Thanks [Giuseppe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/67312/giuseppe) for saving 2 chars.

```r
for(i in 3:1)cat(i,format(runif(1,.5),,2)," ")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/Py2/SCNTITNPwdjKUDM5sUQjUwcolAtkFJXmZaZpGOromWrq6Bhp6igpKGn@/w8A)

Comment: I believe `runif()` by default has the left and right endpoints as `0` and `1` respectively, so `runif(1,.5)` should work the same for -2 bytes in both.

Comment: Good catch thanks @Giuseppe.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 58 bytes

```python
from time import*
for a in'321':print a;sleep(1-time()%.5)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P60oP1ehJDM3VSEztyC/qESLKy2/SCFRITNP3djIUN2qoCgzr0Qh0bo4JzW1QMNQF6RUQ1NVz1Tz/38A)

I created a very simple random number generator that takes the seed time (as many people do).

---

Improvements

- From 63 to 58 bytes by [Jonathan Allan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/53748/jonathan-allan)
- [MagicOctopus Urn](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59376/magic-octopus-urn) suggested swapping sleep and count down.

Comment: `1-time()%.5` should do the trick. (You need `[3,2,1]` by the way)

Comment: Also `for a in'321'` [saves another two](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P60oP1ehJDM3VSEztyC/qESLKy2/SCFRITNP3djIUN2qOCc1tUDDUBekRENTVc9U07qgKDOvRCHx/38A)

Comment: @JonathanAllan Very good point, updated.

Comment: This sleeps once before the countdown too. I think you need the print statement before the sleep.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn Agreed, updated.

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <strike>75</strike> <strike>65</strike> 60 bytes

- thanks to @Shaggy for reducing by 10 bytes
- thanks to @Kevin Cruijssen for reducing by 5 bytes

```javascript
f=(i=3)=>i&&setTimeout(f,Math.random()*500+500,i-1,alert(i))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HczBDYMwDADAbZBNA6KqeIYN@LGABU7rKsQocbt@QDzue1/6U1mzHNYl3bhS5Gx@1VQ0ch/1XYMH8S/0kzRNYVtkZ/0ZBDeTffpMadMdsB2H4XFx0j3dnYAg1gBYTw)

Comment: [55 bytes](https://tio.run/##HctBCoAgEADAr3RJFDSM6GinntAHxNbYMDdyq@cbNPfZ/eNLuPBkk2mF6hNc7ALlQgm6RFuNTqIblJtQiAK84AF0s4y6h8FkeJvZM7SjtRpNr/8vUakapaof)

Comment: @Shaggy will it really be random if you're using Date ? (for the second time the random occured)

Comment: Why `*1000%500+500`? You can just use `*500+500`.

Comment: With the updates to the spec, it probably won't be random enough but it might be worth asking for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, 122 bytes

```
import random as r,time
def w():time.sleep(abs(r.random()-.5)+.5)
print(3,end="");w();print(", 2",end="");w();print(", 1")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEoMS8lP1chsVihSKckMzeVKyU1TaFcQ9MKxNErzklNLdBITCrWKNKDqNTQ1NUz1dQGYq6Cosy8Eg1jndS8FFslJU1roC5riJiSjoKREnZxQyXN//8B)

Comment: You need the imports

Comment: [On scoring imported functions](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8288/34718)

Comment: Whoops! It's been fixed.

Answer (score 1):

## APL+WIN, 37 bytes

```
3⋄r←⎕dl ↑n←.49+.01×2?51⋄2⋄r←⎕dl 1↓n⋄1
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 39 bytes

Gradually tweaked down to 39 bytes, thanks to @jonathan-allan + @xcali.

```perl
say-$_+select$a,$a,$a,1-rand.5for-3..-1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVJXJV67ODUnNblEJVEHggx1ixLzUvRM0/KLdI319HQN////l19QkpmfV/xf19dUz8DQAAA)

Comment: would `1-rand(.5)` work?

Comment: Good idea.  Can then use `1-rand.5` too.

Comment: Cut four more bytes by removing the parens and changing the counter to be negative.  [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVJXJV67ODUnNblEJVEHggx1ixLzUvRM0/KLdI319HQN////l19QkpmfV/xf19dUz8DQAAA "Perl 5 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, 86 bytes

```java
v->{for(int i=0;++i<4;Thread.sleep((int)(Math.random()*500+500)))System.out.print(i);}
```

Prints without delimiter. If that is not allowed it's +2 bytes by changing `print` to `println` (new-line delimiter).

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##ZU@xbsIwEN37FTfajbAywOTSjREWEAtiuDqmMTh2ZF8CCOXb00vTrdI9nZ7u6d57V@xxca1uo/GYM2zRhdcbgAtk0wWNhd1EAfroKjDiOK1eUp3iPcPmYWxLLgbNmoHBkwnJGdhBgDWM/eLzdYlJ8D9w61IXhftY6kOdLFYqe2tbMd2k2CLVKmGoYiPk@6osC4aUcv/MZBsVO1JtYqVwUg@jnr3a7suz15/lb8SGC4g9sfT7dAb8l3RuE5QRofNezsGH8Qc)
[Prove the intervals are in the correct range of `[500, 1000)` ms.](https://tio.run/##HYu9CoMwFEZ3n@LDKakoUnCS9g2cHEuHW@3PtSYRcxVK8dnT2OHjG845A62UD/07hG4k79EQ228CTMtt5A5eSOKtjnuYiFQrM9vn5QrSuwY83KzYCvh0rGpwnp/LGvqPgPbj5W4Kt0gxxU5Gq3ZZq4bkVcxke2eUPlRlmcXpLIXxqa5jvSVbCD8)

**Explanation:**

```java
v->{                        // Method with empty unused parameter and no return-type
  for(int i=0;++i<4;        //  Loop in range [1,4)
      Thread.sleep((int)(Math.random()*500+500)))
                            //    After every iteration: sleep for [500, 1000) ms randomly
     System.out.print(i);}  //   Print the current number
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Chip](https://github.com/Phlarx/chip) `-wingjj`, 33 bytes

```
0123456e7f s
???????p*9S!ZZZtaABb
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S87ILPj/38DQyNjE1CzVPE2hmMseAgq0LIMVo6KiShIdnZL@//@vW56Zl56VBQA)

In Chip, we cannot wait for exactly <sup>1</sup>/<sub>100</sub> of a second, but we can wait for <sup>1</sup>/<sub>256</sub> of a second, so we use that here.

`p`, when asked, will pause execution for the stack head (one byte) * <sup>1</sup>/<sub>256</sub> seconds. On each cycle, we always set the high bit of the stack (<sup>128</sup>/<sub>256</sub>) and set all other stack bits randomly (with the `?`'s). This gives an even distribution between 0.50 and 1.00 seconds.

Some of the args, `-w` and `-gjj`, specify that the input, instead of using stdin, should be a countdown from `0xFF` to `0x00` (then wrapping). We use this to provide the low two bits for counting down. All other output bits remain constant (at the value corresponding to ASCII `0`).

Finally, once we are done, we terminate the program with `t`, preventing a pause after the last number.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <sup><s>21</s></sup> 18 bytes

```
3RṚðṄṛ50r³÷³XœS@ð/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AScA2P9qZWxsef//M1LhuZrDsOG5hOG5mzUwcsKzw7fCs1jFk1NAw7Av//8)

-3 bytes from xigoi.

### Explanation

from caird coinheringaahing.

```
3RṚðṄṛ50r³÷³XœS@ð/ - Main link. Takes no arguments on the left
3R                 - Generate the range [1, 2, 3]
  Ṛ                - Reverse it
   ð            ð  - Define a dyadic chain f(a, b):
    Ṅ              -   Print a
     ṛ             -   Replace a with b
      50r³         -   Yield a range [50, 51, ..., 100]
          ÷³       -   Divide each by 100; Yields [0.5, 0.51, ..., 1]
            X      -   Take a random element t
             œS@   -   Sleep for t seconds then return b
                 / - Reduce the range by the dyadic chain.
                     Remember, f(a, b) = b (with some side effects), so this runs:
                     f(f(3, 2), 1) = f(2, 1) = 1, printing a each time (3, 2, 1)
```

Comment: 18 bytes: `3RṚðṄṛ50r³÷³XœS@ð/` (also fixes the problem that your program can't generate 0.5)

Comment: @xigoi That's a brilliant use of `/`, `ṛ` and `œS`!

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 12 bytes

```
V_S3N.d-1O.5
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/Pyw@2NhPL0XX0F/P9P9/AA)

---

Python 3 translation:

```
V_S3         | for N in range(1, 4)[::-1]:
    N        |     print(N)
     .d-1O.5 |     time.sleep(1 - random.uniform(0, 0.5))
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Nim](http://nim-lang.org/), 70 bytes

```
import os,random
randomize()
for i in[3,2,1]:echo i;sleep 500.rand+500
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8vM/f8/M7cgv6hEIb9YpygxLyU/lwtCZValamhypeUXKWQqZOZFG@sY6RjGWqUmZ@QrZFoX56SmFiiYGhjogRRrAxn//wMA)

Answer (score 0):

## [GAWK], 57 bytes

```
BEGIN{while(a++<2){print 4-a;sleep(rand()/2+0.5)}print 1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v/fydXd06@6PCMzJ1UjUVvbxkizuqAoM69EwUQ30bo4JzW1QKMoMS9FQ1PfSNtAz1SzFiJrWPv//7/8gpLM/Lzi/7q6OfmJKbYlmbmpAA)